# Switch Data Source for Tableau Sheet

Tags: tableau-api

Given that `Tableau` apparently refuses to allow proper editing of the `Data Source` I have resorted to creating a new one from scratch.

The screenshot shows the situation:  the old Data Source "NY FIPS 5" is still being attached to the Worksheet.

[image]

The intention is to use the new DataSource  `usCountyCrimeSummary` : however it is unclear ( to me at least) how to disconnect the old Data Source from the existing sheet and then attach the new DataSource to that sheet.

The big surprise was when clicking on `Edit Connection` it did *not* allow *selecting a different Data Source* : instead it went into the *properties of the existing Data Source*. So then how to *switch* the Data Source?

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note is that switching data sources will change for all sheets connected to that data source. If you only need to change the data source for one sheet out of many, copy that sheet to a new workbook, change it there, then copy it back.

Perhaps your broken data connection needs to be fixed first, but to change a data source go Data > Replace Data Source

Comment: Switching for all sheets is ok. The issue shown above is *how* to switch. I will look again to see if your suggestion `Data | Replace Data Source` were available.

Comment: You'll have to fix the broken source first and go to a sheet were there is data from the source you want to switch out of.